# Extension created for public schema not available within database

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-extensions

So, I create the `citext` extension for `schema public` and I can see it's there, but then it's not available within the database in that schema. The database is in `public` as well, because it's created from the `postgres` user and no schema is specified at the creation. Here's a screenshot with some more data:
[image]

So, you can see that the extension is there, but once I connect to the database, it's not available anymore and I basically have to install it within the database. Any ideas how to make it available initially for the database as well?

PgSQL `v9.6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

You are actually using (at least) **two** databases. You are installing `CITEXT` in the wrong one.

**Longer answer**

In the first database (whose name is not shown), you install `CITEXT`. This database is probably the `postgres` database, which is created by default when you install PostgreSQL.

Then you use the `\c` command and you switch to **another** database (`sensordata`). You need to create your extension in this database.

That is, you should do:

```
\c sensordata 
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
\dx
```

If you need to use the `citext` module in more databases, you need to install it in each one. The extensions on the other databases don't matter. Databases do not interfere with each other.

Every PostgreSQL cluster (=database installation) [has (by default) one database named `postgres`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370525/default-database-named-postgres-on-postgresql-server). If you use `psql`, it is the one to which you connect "by default". You don't actually need to have a `postgres` database. I guess the `postgres`database is where you installed the `CITEXT` extension.

Within every PostgreSQL database, there is, by default, one **public** schema.

---

PostgreSQL does not work like (for instance) MySQL, where you can acces several databases at once through a single connection (provided you have a user with the right permissions).

In PostgreSQL you access **one** database through a single connection. Within a database, you can access **as many schemas** as needed. The role that *schemas* play in PostgreSQL is nearly the same as the one played by a *database* in MySQL.

See also:

- [Relationship between catalog, schema, user, and database instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942520/relationship-between-catalog-schema-user-and-database-instance)
- [What's the difference between a catalog and a schema in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022755/whats-the-difference-between-a-catalog-and-a-schema-in-a-relational-database)

Answer (score 0):

stumpling over this.

If you want to make extension available for all new creates databases you can utilize the postgres template system. The command `CREATE DATABASE` creates a copy of the database `template1`  (if no other templated was parameterized). So you can:

1. create a new database `template_with_ext_dont_use`
2. connect to `template_with_ext_dont_use` and `create extension foo`
3. create new databases with `CREATE DATABASE foobar TEMPLATE template_with_ext_dont_use;`

The new Database "foobar" is an copy of "template_with_ext_dont_use" and has your extension installed.